# How can I bind an (outbound, of course) HttpUrlConnection to a specific local ip address, when I have multiple NIC on my client machine?

Tags: java, http, networking

I have a kind of Http-Gateway app, which acts as an http client towards servers outside our local network.

There is going to be a network configuration upgrade, and I'm going to have problems because:
 - there are multiple network cards on client machine
 - firewall/nat rules use hardwired ip addresses

If I could programmatically force HttpUrlConnection object to use a specific ip address, I would be ok. But I'm afraid it can't be done.

Am I right? If not, which version of JRE supports it?

Other possible solutions, preferably ones which don't involve rewriting everything from scratch?
The simpler the better: I know, there is Apache HttpClient, or I could use Sockets...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see no good solution but have two poor possibilities:

1. Proxy the connections locally:

   ```
   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(
           "proxy", 5555));
   URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection(proxy);
   ```
2. Register a custom `URLStreamHandlerFactory` with `java.net.URL`. Whenever `openConnection()` is called on the `URL` it would be handled by this registered custom factory, giving you control over details of the socket connection. Either use Apache's implementation or roll your own?

   ```
   Url.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URLStreamHandlerFactory fac)
   ```

Comment: Good catch on the URLStreamHandlerFactory! I was looking for something like that. It also invalidates the middle paragraph of my answer.

Comment: The URLStreamHandlerFactory's no use sadly. See ZZ Coder's comment below.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. HttpURLConnection doesn't provide any interface to manipulate the socket.

You shouldn't do this either. Selection of interface is based on routing decision. If you have to manually select the NIC to get to the destination, all your internet connection would have the same issue. You should add static route in the OS to make sure the correct interface is used for the destination.

Comment: With regard to all connections having the same issue: indeed, C apps have already been dealt with. 
Your objection that NIC / ip addr selection should not be a programming issue makes sense. 
I must talk with our sysadmins, this is good old Tandem NonStop machines we're talking about.

Comment: If this is on Tandem, you can't even do it with socket in Java. The interface needs to be set with a custom call socket_transport_name_set(), which is not even available in Java.

Comment: Isn't it OK just to call Socket.bind ()? Or maybe this interferes with socket lifecycle management performed by the HttpUrlConnection?

Comment: I mean: Socket.bind (localIpAddr)

Comment: It's useful to select outbound IP when you have multiple public IP addresses and you want to be visible to world with specific one of them ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's a constructor on the Socket class ( http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html ) that will let you specify a localAddr. This makes it *possible* to do what you want in Java.

Unfortunately, HttpUrlConnection and its family of classes don't give you much opportunity to get at the underlying socket. I followed the possibility offered by `setContentHandlerFactory`  but that only lets you manipulate the content long after the socket's been opened.

My suggestion, therefore, would be to twist your admin's arm into changing the routing table of your machine such that the only one possible (or optimal) route from that machine to your target hosts will go through the gateway you want to use. That way, when a socket connection is opened it will default to the card for that gateway.